# Prove that $A - (B - C) \neq (A - B) - C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This one has me stumped. I've been able to demonstrate this using Venn Diagrams, and my initial proof was essentially a verbal description of my Venn Diagram. However, my professor explained to me the utter lack of formality in this approach, and I agree with him there. I am just truly puzzled as to how to do this.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to show something like this is to provide a *concrete* counterexample.  Find three sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ for which the right and left side are different - like $A = \{0,1,42\}$, etc.

[Note that $A \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \setminus C$ if for example $A = \emptyset$, so you won't be able to find a proof that $A \setminus (B \setminus C) \neq (A \setminus B) \setminus C$ holds for *all* sets $A$, $B$, and $C$.]

Comment: Let A = {1, 2, 3}; B = {2, 3, 4}; C = {3, 4, 5}. (B - C) = {2}. A - (B - C) = {1, 3}. (A - B) = {1}. (A - B) - C = {1}. {1, 3} $\neq$ {1}.

Was something like this what you were describing? It doesn't seem quite as formal as the answer given by user46944, but I haven't even learned enough to understand the notation there.

Comment: @Jonson Sorry, I didn't realize which level you are at.  Giving an example like you've done is definitely formal.  And it proves the fact that they are not equal.  Because if they were equal, they should be equal for any example you can think of, but you came up with an example where the equality doesn't hold.  That's formal.

Comment: @Jonson: Yep, that was exactly what I meant.

Comment: @user46944 Alright, I see. Thank you so much for your input! Your proof seems fascinating as a way of figuring out exactly what type of concrete counterexample is needed, and I look forward to eventually knowing enough to understand it fully. :)

Comment: @Frunobulax Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Idea for a counterexample: take $B=C\ne\emptyset$ strictly contained in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for any sets $A, B$ in a universal set $X$, $A - B = A \cap B^{c}$.

So, assuming $A, B, C$ are subsets of some universal set $X$, we have:

$A - (B - C) = A - B \cap C^{c} = A \cap (B \cap C^{c})^{c} = A \cap (B^{c} \cup C)$.  (At the last step, I used one of DeMorgan's laws that says $(X \cap Y)^{c} = X^{c} \cup Y^{c}$.)

Now, $(A - B) - C = (A \cap B^{c}) - C = A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c}$.

It's easy to prove that in general $A \cap (B^{c} \cup C)$ is not equal to $A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c}$.  Specifically, you can come up with an example where $A \cap C$ is non-empty.  Then, elements of $A \cap C$ are in $A \cap (B^{c} \cup C)$, but not in $A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c}$.

Comment: After doing a bit more reading, I can see that your answer is along the same lines as that of @Frunobulax. I haven't learned any of DeMorgan's laws yet, so I don't think I can safely apply this without truly understanding it.

In terms of formality, would the sample explanation I provided in response to the other answer hold up? It seems like it's just an example of what you conclude is needed here.

Comment: I replied on the other answer. I wish I could vote up both of you, but I sadly don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Jonson Haha, no worries.  As long as you understand, that's the most important thing.